# Where to d3 sort this data for sankey / different browsers

Tags: sorting, d3.js, sankey-diagram

I've got a Sankey diagram in d3: 
http://greencracker.github.io/test/

I'd like both the nodes & the links to sort from biggest at the top to smallest at the bottom.

I've got nodes sorted like I want, by modifying sankey.js like so:

```
  function center(node) {
  // return node.y + node.dy / 2;
  return 0;}
```

Just  with that modification, it looks perfect on Safari 8.

In Firefox, Chrome, nodes still sort from big to small like I'd like, yay!

But links are sorting from smallest ones at the top to big ones at the bottom.

Where to specify the sort so that all the browsers sort like I want?  I would think somewhere in index.html?

Any ideas?

Screenshots here of what I'm after:
http://greencracker.net/?p=2237

Comment: Your edit of the function `center` is .... really strange. In order to sort nodes by size, you should do `.sort(function(a,b){return a.dy-b.dy})` on your node list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to modify the relaxLeftToRight, and relaxRightToLeft functions. Here are the updated functions:

```
function relaxLeftToRight(alpha) {
  nodesByBreadth.forEach(function(nodes, breadth) {
    nodes.forEach(function(node) {
      if (node.targetLinks.length) {
        // Value-weighted average of the y-position of source node centers linked to this node.
        // var y = d3.sum(node.targetLinks, weightedSource) / d3.sum(node.targetLinks, value);
        var y = d3.sum(node.targetLinks) ;
        node.y += (y - center(node)) * alpha;
      }
    });
  });

  function weightedSource(link) {
    return (link.source.y + link.sy + link.dy / 2) * link.value;
  }
}

function relaxRightToLeft(alpha) {
  nodesByBreadth.slice().reverse().forEach(function(nodes) {
    nodes.forEach(function(node) {
      if (node.sourceLinks.length) {
        // Value-weighted average of the y-positions of target nodes linked to this node.
        // var y = d3.sum(node.sourceLinks, weightedTarget) / d3.sum(node.sourceLinks, value);
        var y = d3.sum(node.sourceLinks);
        node.y += (y - center(node)) * alpha;
      }
    });
  });

  function weightedTarget(link) {
    return (link.target.y + link.ty + link.dy / 2) * link.value;
  }
}
```

This example will sort by largest to smallest.

Comment: I took a clean copy of sankey.js and made only these modifications & it works.  So, I got rid of my edit of function center. (Which yes, was "weird.")

Answer (score 1):

use a function like

```
function ascendingLinkSize(a, b) {
  return a.value - b.value;
  // return 0;
}
```

to sort by link size rather than node positions

Answer (score 0):

In the function

```
function ascendingTargetDepth(a, b) {
  return a.target.y + b.target.y;
  // return 0;
}
```

You should have `a.target.y - b.target.y;` instead.